# Rewrite Rule with Rewrite Map

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, isapi-rewrite, rewritemap

I got a problem with the creation of rewrite rule which is using a rewrite map in IIS. The goal is to rewrite requests like `/Japan/test.html` or `/Chile/test.html` to `jp/en/simple-test` and `cl/en/simple-test`.

Here is the rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite sites" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/(.*)/test.html$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{Sites:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/en/simple-test" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

And this is my rewrite map:

```
<rewriteMap name="Sites">
  <add key="chile" value="cl" />
  <add key="japan" value="jp" />
</rewriteMap>
```

So once again, I want to dynamically translate all the languages into language codes and rewrite to `language_code/en/simple-test`. I want to use rewrite map as there will be more languages.

Comment: @GhostCat I've no idea what are you talking about. Not only I've voted this question as "Requires Editing" - there are 3 of us which thinks the same. So it's not only me who thinks that this question should be re-edited.

Comment: @GhostCat Whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of tests, I was finally able to solve my problem. Here is how `Rewrite Rule` and `Rewrite Map` should look like for above conditions:

```
<rule name="Rewrite sites" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/test.html$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{Sites:{R:1}}" pattern="(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/en/simple-test" />
</rule>

<rewriteMap name="Sites">
  <add key="chile" value="/cl" />
  <add key="japan" value="/jp" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Tip! If you don't known what is in {R:0}, {R:1}, {C:0} or {C:1} back referenced create fake rewrite action e.g.: `<action type="Rewrite" url="www.test.com?a={C:1}" />` and in the `a` param you will see specyfic back reference content.